# Way to do basic WAN optimization between two Linux servers that splits single connection into multiple parallel ones?

Tags: linux, centos, tcp, tcpip, wide-area-network

There are utilities on Linux that allow you to work around WAN conditions which cause you to not be able to utilize your full bandwidth.  They do this by performing multiple requests in parallel (for example, lftp and its pget command).

Is there some basic WAN optimization method / tool available for Linux (specifically CentOS) which will cause all traffic between two servers (possibly just on one port would be fine) to be split across multiple simultaneous connections in parallel (transparently to applications of course), so that programs/utilities which can't do parallel connections can still achieve maximum throughput.  I know some utilities can be parallelized using some tricks with xargs, but for ones that don't support that this is relevant, and plus it's nice to have it be transparent to keep things simple.

I tried searching on Google and serverfault but didn't have much luck.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Umm. Are you looking for a solution to use more than one physical link to the remote site transparently? Or do you think that having more than one TCP connection to the remote site would automagically multiply the available bandwidth? Because it really would not. Citing lftp / pget as a reputed example does not help matters here as downloading files from QoS'ed or Throughput-per-connection-constrained public servers is a different thing entirely.

Comment: Just one physical link.  Celada posted below and I just added some replies to that post.

Answer (score 1):

If using multiple connections in parallel helps you use more bandwidth than a single connection, then the reason is the TCP window. If the bandwidth delay product between the two ends of the transfer is large, the optimal TCP window size may be larger than the maximum size that the TCP stacks on one or both ends is willing to use. Using more than one TCP connection lets you multiply the effective window size.

It follows from this that no amount of tunelling at layer 3 or below will achieve the same effect. No matter what kind of tunnel you build, the tunnel's payload is still TCP connections, and if there is only one of them, it will max out its window.

Your only choices are:

- Increase the kernel's maximum TCP window sizes on both ends of the transfer.
- Use more than one TCP connection in your application.
- Build a tunnel at layer 4 or above. This could be for example a proxy server like an HTTP or socks proxy, or a simple TCP connection forwarder where you connect to localhost and it forwards the connection elsewhere. The tunnel software could carry the traffic load balanced over multiple underlying TCP connections (or it could do something else completely).

  I am not aware of any software that does this.

Comment: The other factor is if you have any packet loss, you take a hit due to TCP's network congestion avoidance algorithm, but if you had at least two connections running in parallel then if one suffers a little slowdown, the other could compensate. Even if both experiences minor packet loss, the aggregate bandwidth available to the two might still equal the maximum link bandwidth which wouldn't be the case with just one.

Comment: @user101203 I guess the second bullet point should have read "Use more than one TCP connection **in your application**". What you are actually talking about (split and recombine) is actually my third bullet point.

Comment: @user101203 If you are concerned about performance hits due to packet loss, you need a different protocol which would add redundancy to deal with it. Using more than one stream only marginally helps matters since a 1% packet loss would hit both streams on an equal rate, causing fast recoveries and slow starts at the same rate as a single connection. If you need to work around WAN conditions where TCP does not perform optimally, really your only options are to either change the behavior of TCP or change the aforementioned conditions.